# Can I say this? "To spank my shoulder when needed"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases

Can I say this: "To spank my shoulder when needed" or "to spank on my shoulder when I'm down in life"? Is there a way instead not using spank? Is there any other way to express the same feeling?

Comment: Please explain: what is the feeling?

Comment: What I mean is ...when you are disappointed in life, you need some one to spank on your shoulder( in the way of encouraging by giving moral support)

Comment: SHould be *pat on the shoulder*

Comment: The connotations for 'spanking' are really only for the rear end and for mild corporal punishment for children. And pretty much nothing else.

Comment: @Mitch: There's a whole slew of NSFW (Not Safe For Work) things you could find online related to spanking and have *nothing* to do with corporal punishment for children.

Comment: @Frustrated: for the OP, the NSFW meanin of spank is directly through the connotations that I gave, that is, for the level of English the OP cares about.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner. I think in BrE *spank* has primarily sexual connotations, with *slap* being used for corporal punishment, while in AmE they're not as clearly differentiated. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 13):

There is some confusion here between several idioms. First, *never* spank anyone on anything as *spanking* is a mild form of corporal punishment and I'm sure you don't mean that.

> a *pat on the back* is giving someone praise
>
> a *pat on the shoulder* is a consolatory gesture (I think this is the one you are thinking of)
>
> a *tap on the shoulder* is either simply getting someone's attention, or calling someone up for promotion or some other more important duty

There isn't really a physical difference between a pat on the back or a pat on the shoulder, it's all about context, but in English we use two phrases to differentiate between the two intentions.

Answer (score 2):

You would not say "Spank your shoulder".

I think you are thinking of "Pat your back" or "Pat you on the back".

"A word or gesture of praise or approval: received a pat on the back for doing a good job."

Answer (score 1):

If the motion is light, I'd go for a "pat on the shoulder". For example, the kind of thing you'd give a friend to console them after their loss. If it's more percussive, I think I'd go for a "clap on the shoulder", such as you might give someone right before they head out onto the field for a game. As noted above, "spank" contains much different associations which I doubt are what you're aiming for.